# Ошибка GET запроса nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Есть такой код

```
var http = require('http');

var url = 'http://www.cyberforum.ru/';

http.get(url, function (res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', (elem) => body +=elem);
    res.on('end', () => console.log(res.statusCode));
});
```

Он завершается ошибкой

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Parse Error
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:607:20)
```

Если я выполню такой код, то он отработает без ошибки

```
var http = require('https');

var url = 'https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html';

http.get(url, function (res) {
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', (elem) => body +=elem);
    res.on('end', () => console.log(res.statusCode));
});
```

Т.е. запросы с шифрованием проходят без ошибки, в то время как обычные страдают. Что не так?

Comment: Допишите обработку ошибок Так же [в справке](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) приведён пример без шифрования

Comment: Ну так добавьте `on('error',...)`  и посмотрите что за ошибка

Comment: Добавил. Пишет Parse Error. Я нашел похожую проблему на форуме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31646143/im-getting-a-parseerror-in-nodejs-and-with-a-really-not-proper-error-message. Самый нижний комментарий видимо ответ. Не знаю как заголовки дублированные удалить - у меня сразу в обработчик ошибки бросается

Comment: Я не вижу дублирования заголовков. Что у вас `curl -I http://www.cyberforum.ru/` показывает?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Tue, 24 Jul 2018 12:09:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=15
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: private
Set-Cookie: bborig_cookieuser=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/
Set-Cookie: bblastvisit=1532434148; expires=Wed, 24-Jul-2019 12:09:08 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/
Set-Cookie: bblastactivity=0; expires=Wed, 24-Jul-2019 12:09:08 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/
x,vitruvian: Quick Ref

Comment: Set-Cookie несколько раз повторяется невсчет?

Comment: Между прочим если делать запрос на http://www.yandex.ru то будет без ошибков и заголовков по одному